# Does windows 10 compromise TOR?

Tags: anonymity, windows, deanonymization

Does running Tor on Windows 10 compromise my security? And further from that, are there any issues I need to be aware of while using Tor on Windows 10?

Comment: I don't see any problem with the question. The issue being is it safe to run TOR on the Windows 10 platform? Pretty straightforward.

Comment: This is an excellent question and is the reason why I came to this site today. Microsoft has gven itself the right to inspect any files on any computer with Windows 10, right in the TOS. Maybe M$ will decide that Tor users are bad people who pose a 'threat' and invade privacy at will.

Comment: That is REALLY unfortunate.  I have always gotten good responses to my questions until now.  I am thinking that perhaps Windows 10 is so new that the experts here don't have an answer yet. - Which would be quite understandable.

Comment: @user3495: `I am thinking that perhaps Windows 10 is so new that the experts here don't have an answer yet.` You're most probably right. Please revisit the same question in two years' time when Windows 10's user base becomes bigger.

Comment: I used to have the Windows 10 platform while running Tor. I noticed that literally 2 days after installing Tor, my internet speed went down into the basement and never recovered. I started seeing black spots on my screen and then got that dreaded blue screen of death, plus this error as well: Driver IRQL Not Less Or Equal. Things got so bad that I had to roll back my computer back to factory settings and reinstall Windows 8.1. After I did that, my computer returned back to normal. I'll see what happens when I reinstall Tor and will update everyone. One thing's certain: will not be upgrading ba

Comment: Correlation does not imply causation.

Answer (score 5):

Windows 10 has a keylogger embedded, thus all the words, codes, psws that user insert using keyboard could be sent to Windows Servers and to authorities per request.

Does it mean we should use "on screen" keyboard or other alternative input (speech) while using Tor? Unfortunately, Windows 10 has camera-logger embedded as well as microphone-logger embedded and a screenshot are pretty simple to make... hence, you almost should have on-screen input keyboard embedded in Tor, otherwise you are transparent.

I am afraid you cannot disable such a keylogging behavior by easy means, thus Windows 10 should compromise Tor as an incognito tool.

All in all, the overall impression using Tor on Windows 10 will compromise any of your activities including Tor usage.

[Source](http://aeronet.cz/news/analyza-windows-10-ve-svem-principu-jde-o-pouhy-terminal-na-sber-informaci-o-uzivateli-jeho-prstech-ocich-a-hlasu/)

Comment: Good points, but do you have links evidencing your statements?

Comment: @AndrewLott Please use this link (google translate) http://aeronet.cz/news/analyza-windows-10-ve-svem-principu-jde-o-pouhy-terminal-na-sber-informaci-o-uzivateli-jeho-prstech-ocich-a-hlasu/

Comment: The keylogger was only used in the Beta so they could see how well things were working. Ars Technica has already covered this. The keylogger is not enabled in the full release. At any rate, if you're worried about Tor on Windows 10, maybe you shouldn't be using Windows at all.