# Is Tor safe for windows ten?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I have been looking up that tor may or may not be for windows 10 and I want to use tor for looking around the deep web. several people said that windows 10 has lots of data that can act as spyware.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does windows 10 compromise TOR?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/7353/does-windows-10-compromise-tor)

Answer (score 1):

No, Tor is not safe if you run it on top of Windows 10. Microsoft is a spyware company.

See [Microsoft's Software is Malware](https://www.gnu.org/proprietary/malware-microsoft.en.html) for more details (e.g Microsoft Surveillance).

> Malware means software designed to function in ways that mistreat or
>   harm the user. (This does not include accidental errors.) This page
>   explains how Microsoft software is malware.

See also similiar question here [Does windows 10 compromise TOR?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/7353/does-windows-10-compromise-tor) with the very clear answer: **Don't use Tor on Windows 10**.